# Fetching URL: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/repository-10.xml Failed

Tags: android

Alright before you mark this as duplicate, none of the duplicate topics presented here and the web helped me. I am not even in proxy and yet I could not update my Android SDK! I really need help. I am not on a proxy and I tried different solutions but to no avail. Any more ideas why I could not update my Android SDK? Also I encountering similar problem with Eclipse MarketPlace but that one was resolved now. I think both of them broke last Monday.

Any suggestions/ideas?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Here are the pings requested[image]

Here is the tracert as well. I don't know how to interpret this but I think I a missing on some hops. Please tell me the next step to do.

[image]

I do not know if this is my ISP. I will try to coordinate this with them as well.

Comment: can you ping dl-ssl.google.com ?

Comment: Hi please see my new edit

Comment: try switching to https instead of http

Comment: How to do that? It still fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, if you ever encountered this error even though you tried all the solutions (including the duplicates of this post) and the issues filed on Google. If you Are using Avast Premier 2015, Turn off its firewall. After turning the firewall it finally worked for me. It took me a week to fix this problem :(.

Answer (score 1):

I tried from checking the checkbox "force https" to disabling windows firewall, running as administrator etc, but didnt work, Then for one last try I disabled the avast firewall and voila it worked like a charm...

Comment: we have the same answer though.